# Optimizing my postgres database which holds over 500k restaurant information

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization, rails-activerecord, large-data

I have a database of all the New York City restaurant inspection data. Currently there are ~520,000 entries and clearly they are not all unique. (i.e. restaurants appear more than once since they have been inspected multiple times.)

I'm creating an app that will display all unique restaurants on a map using the google maps API based on grade and zip code. Currently our search time is shit as there are so many records.

Any suggestions on whats the best type of hash index we can set up to to optimize our search? Also, what would be the best way to delete all non-unique restaurants with the latest inspection data?

The database is running on postgres with Active Record. Our migration is as follows:

```
    create_table :restaurants do |t|
  t.string :CAMIS
  t.string :DBA
  t.string :BORO
  t.string :BUILDING
  t.string :STREET
  t.string :ZIPCODE
  t.string :PHONE
  t.string :CUISINECODE
  t.string :INSPDATE
  t.string :ACTION
  t.string :VIOLCODE
  t.string :SCORE
  t.string :CURRENTGRADE
  t.string :GRADEDATE
  t.string :RECORDDATE

  t.timestamps
end
```

(Please don't mind the uppercases. changes coming on next migration)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the query that you are using.

Comment: Without the query we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer your looking for (or hoping for), but IMO, the answer is to come up with a good relational schema design.  I don't completely understand your system, but it sounds like you need a `restaurant` table and an `inspection` table (1:Many relationship) and a foreign key between them.  Then you need to figure out what uniquely identifies a restaurant and create the appropriate index to enforce that.

Comment: Indeed. Have a separate table to track inspections, set a flag in that table to mark the latest inspection?